# Opengl disable color interpolation

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, glfw

How to disable color interpolation in GLFW and OpenGL 3.3 so that left half of the screen is pure white and the other half is completely black instead of having smooth transition through all shades of gray?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to disable interpolation from a global standpoint because that's all shaders do (most of everything is 0 to 1 or -1 to 1). Instead, what you want to do is round values via floor or ceil, or shape them with functions like smoothstep and pow. Simondev actually did a course on doing things exactly like what you're asking in his [GLSL shader course](https://simondev.teachable.com/p/glsl-shaders-from-scratc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interpolation of a vertex shader output can be changed with a [Interpolation qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers). Using the `flat` qualifier an output will not be interpolated.

e.g.:

Vertex shader

```c
flat out vec3 color;
```

Fragment shader

```c
flat in vec3 color;
```